# Use firefox profile but lost all data selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Automatically login gmail with selenium webdriver but when I close the browser and open it again normally, even I use selenium webdriver go to gmail, I must login again. Why? 
This is my code

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile (r"K:\Desktop\Kiranaf\Profile")

options = Options()
options.set_preference('media.peerconnection.enabled', False)
options.set_preference('javascript.enabled', False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = fp,options = options)

driver.get("http://gmail.com")
...
```

Thanks for reply my question !!! :(

Comment: Here's the link to the spec: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#sessions.

Comment: you are creating a fresh profile every time you run that code.  why would you expect it to contain saved credentials or cookies if you didn't instruct it to?